# Boolean - It doesn't stop when it should (JAVA)

Tags: java, button, jframe, boolean, jpanel

So i'm almost at the finish line right now and having trouble with stopping my music when choosing a new song or to play a new song.

```
static boolean thread2Status = false;

btnPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btnPlay) {
            if(thread2Status) {
                mp3_player.play();
                lblPlaying.setText("Enjoy the music!");

            }
            else if(!thread2Status) {
                stop();
            }
        }

    }       
});

btnOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == btnOpen) {

            try {
                if(thread2Status = true) {
                    Choose();


                } else if(!thread2Status) {
                    stop();
                }

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
});
```

As you guys can see. there is two buttons, one for <kbd>Play</kbd> button and one for <kbd>Open</kbd> button (<kbd>Open</kbd> button has a method where the FileChooser and so on is so there is nothing special there) however. I named a method for `stop()` where the music stops when it should too. I tried if the function worked and it does so there is nothing wrong with the method but this code.

As you guys see I might be confused with the booleans and what I'm trying to do is to make something like this:

First I pick a song so I use the <kbd>Open</kbd> button and choose a file. then I press <kbd>Play</kbd> to get the song  playing. (Here ->) so Whenever I play Open again, the music should stop. thats what I was thinking to do but I can't get it to work. I might be blind right now but all help would be appreciated!

EDIT 1.1:

```
btnPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (e.getSource() == btnPlay) {
                        if(thread2Status) {
                            mp3_player.play();
                            lblPlaying.setText("Enjoy the music!");
                        }
                        else if(!thread2Status) {
                            stop();
                        }
                        thread2Status = !thread2Status;  // this line switches boolean
                    }
                }
            });

            btnOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if(e.getSource() == btnOpen) {

                        try {
                            if(thread2Status) { // not necessary to explicit compare booleans
                                Choose();
                            } else if(!thread2Status){
                                stop();
                            }
                            thread2Status = !thread2Status;  // this line switches boolean


                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();


                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

The issue that happends now is that I have to double click on <kbd>Open</kbd> and <kbd>Play</kbd> to make it work

EDIT PART 2.0 ( Issue with Open button where I have to double click for it)

```
btnOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == btnOpen) {
                    try {
                        if(sant) { 
                            Choose();
                        } else{
                            stop();
                        }
                        sant = !sant;  


                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        System.out.println("we been balling");


                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

sant = true, 
falsk = false

EDIT part 4.0 got it to work by removing if-else statement in Openbutton!

Comment: `if(thread2Status = true)`

Comment: To check for equality use `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Think about what AntiHeadshot means and then about why you didn't just use `if(thread2Status)` (and maybe a better name for the flag). Addionally, this bug should be easy to find in a debugger.

Comment: Ops my bad! Changed it to if(thread2Status)  I took the name because sounded easier for me but yes :) anyways its still doesn't work hmm. I will try with debug and come back

Comment: If you want to stop the music whenever you click the `btnOpen` just put `stop()` before `if(thread2Status)` so it will always be executed

Comment: It gives me `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException` If I do that you said F. Lumnitz

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this project's [MediaPlayer](https://github.com/dberm22/DBoard/blob/master/src/com/dberm22/utils/MediaPlayer.java) class. You would also want to add the [jars](https://github.com/dberm22/DBoard/tree/master/lib) to your lib folder in order to support multiple file formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes

- `if(thread2Status = true)` you are assigning, not comparing! just use `if(thread2Status)`
- you never update your `boolean` flag, so the flow of the program in the `if` is always the same

```
if (e.getSource() == btnPlay) {
     if(thread2Status) {
          mp3_player.play();
          lblPlaying.setText("Enjoy the music!");
     }
     else {
          stop();
    }
    thread2Status = !thread2Status;  // this line switches boolean
}
```

and

```
if(e.getSource() == btnOpen) {
    try {
        if(thread2Status) { // not necessary to explicit compare booleans
            Choose();
        } else {
            stop();
        }
        thread2Status = !thread2Status;  // this line switches boolean


    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm, now im getting ´Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at guis.GUIFrame.stop(GUIFrame.java:234)
 at guis.GUIFrame$3.actionPerformed(GUIFrame.java:197)´ when trying to press Open button. Should I write "thread2Status = true"; inside it?

Comment: which contains the line?

Comment: on the btnOpen which says `} else {
       stop();`

Comment: then you have an error in the `stop()` method... debug it to see what is causing the `NPE`... but according [StackOverflow rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) this should be posted as a new question...

Comment: hmm. I think i know the problem. since our `boolean thread2Status = false;` starts at false. it means that it starts directly at stop() if im right?

Comment: yes, that makes sense, change it to `true` also think about if you need just one `boolean` or more than one, and what the flow of the program must do... I would recommend again to debug....

Comment: Ok, I will try that. It worked but then I have to press two times at the button for a reason too now.. and also it still can play two music at the same time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94906/discussion-between-thrillofit123-and-jordi-castilla).

Comment: Okey it works now well. the only issue now is that I have double click on the Open and Play button

Comment: I got play to work, now the only issue is Open. I still have to double click for it and I can't see it even through debug, any tips?

Comment: @Thrillofit123 check at the chat the new sollution to see if works for you

Comment: Please check again :) Answered you!

Comment: @Thrillofit123 glad you solved it finally. We're here to help. Also, try removing the part `if (e.getSource() == btnPlay) {` as I told you by chat